# Is it possible to get current system time from any of YARA modules?

Tags: payara, yara

As a part of assignment I have to write a **YARA rule that identifies binaries compiled in the last 24 hours**. For this, I need to write a condition in YARA rule where it compares the compile time of binary with the current system time to check whether it's compiled in last 24 hours or not.

*How can I get the current system time within YARA ?*